# Use key value from ng-repeat to extend scope expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I try to use key value from ng-repeat as enlargement of another scope.arrayResult, so in result i would have arrayResult.q1/q2/q3 etc...

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key,x) in data">
     <li><h4>Question: {{x}}</h4>
     <p>{{ arrayResult.[key][0].value }} People Voted: {{ arrayResult. [key][0].label }}</p>
</ul>
```

When i Use key value in angular brackets it works

```
       <p>{{key}}</p>
```

How should look proper expression in which i use key value from ng-repeat which in effect would give me this:

arrayResult.q1[0].value ?

q1 should be result of using [key] value from ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you dont need `.` before bracket notation:

```
{{ arrayResult[key][0].value }}
```